# Chart.js configuring x axis so that the spaces are not always equal

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, charts, chart.js

```js
createLineChart() {

        this.lineChartEl = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [10, 11, 17, 18, 19, 23],
                datasets: [
                {
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#C4CEE5',
                    label: 'recorded values',
                    borderColor: '#C4CEE5',
                    pointBorderColor: '#ffff',
                    pointBackgroundColor: '#ffff',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#C4CEE5',
                    pointRadius: 7,
                    borderCapStyle: 'square',
                    borderJoinStyle: 'round',
                    borderWidth: 1.5,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    data: [23, 34, 45, 12, 45, 65],
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    spanGaps: false,
                }]
            },
            options : {
                legend: {
                        display: false,
                        position: 'top',
                        fullWidth: true,
                    },
                scaleOverride: true,
                scaleSteps: 10,
                scaleStepWidth: 20,
                scaleStartValue: 0,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            suggestMax: max,
                            maxTicksLimit: 4,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            padding: 30
                        },
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            maxTicksLimit: 5,
                            autoSkip: false,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        },
                        time: {
                            unit: 'day',
                            unitStepSize: 1,
                            displayFormats: {
                                day: 'MMM D'
                            },
                        },

                        gridLines : {
                            display : false,
                            drawBorder: false,
                            color: 'transparent',
                        },
                    }]
                },
            },
         });
    };
```

I have created a chart.js line chart where the values on the x axis are dates. I think by default, chart.js plots data with an equal amount of distance between the points regardless of the value of the data. 

I would like it so there is a large space in the chart if the dates are further apart.

 
I have tried using chart-scatter the plugin for chart.js but have not had much luck as I am using ionic/angular but if you have any experience with it that would be great!



What I would like the chart to look like with more space depending on the x-axis value:

Comment: Could you provide some code, or the example for what you are trying to achieve (it looks like you started to!)

Comment: @perfect5th I just added some code but it wont run because I have to refactor. Super annoying that stack overflow doesn't let you post pictures when you're new as they display what I am trying to do better!

Comment: That is not possible !!

Comment: @Elise you have to create your own library I think for that.